# What is the 3rd param in jQuery.proxy used for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery API doc, the jQuery.proxy function usage:

```
jQuery.proxy( function, context )
```

---

**function** The function whose context will be changed.
**context** The object to which the context (this) of the function should be set.

```
jQuery.proxy( context, name )
```

---

**context** The object to which the context of the function should be set.
**name** The name of the function whose context will be changed (should be a property of the context object).

```
proxy : function(fn, proxy, thisObject){
    if ( arguments.length === 2 ) {
        if (typeof proxy === "string" ) {
        thisObject = fn;
        fn = thisObject[proxy];
        proxy = undefined;
    } else if ( proxy && !jQuery.isFunction( proxy ) ) {
        thisObject = proxy;
        proxy = undefined;
    }
}
   if ( !proxy && fn ) {
   proxy = function() {
   return fn.apply( thisObject || this, arguments );
   };
}
// So proxy can be declared as an argument
return proxy;
}
```

But when I look into jQuery source code, of function *proxy*. I found there're 3 parameters declared.

So I wonder what's the use of third param, cannot understand the code :(

I write a code segment to test the function.

```
var someObj = { somefnc : function() {} };
function fnc() {
    this.somefnc();
    console.log(arguments);
}
var proxyedFnc = jQuery.proxy(fnc, undefined, someObj, "arg1","arg2");
proxyedFnc();
//output: []
```

And I wonder why the arguments were not passed to fnc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the source comes from **jquery-1.7.2.js**, Are you sure you check the same version between source and api doc?

```
// Bind a function to a context, optionally partially applying any
// arguments.
proxy: function( fn, context ) {
    if ( typeof context === "string" ) {
        var tmp = fn[ context ];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }

    // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec
    // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Simulated bind
    var args = slice.call( arguments, 2 ),
        proxy = function() {
            return fn.apply( context, args.concat( slice.call( arguments ) ) );
        };

    // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
    proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || proxy.guid || jQuery.guid++;

    return proxy;
},
```

Comment: My Code comes from jQuery 1.5.1. But I don't find any later changes in API doc

Comment: @ThemeZ That is not really relevant, since you are asking about the source code, not the API.

Comment: @ThemeZ i don’t think you will find what you are looking for anyway, the things you ask are not a part of the official docs so it might as well look exactly the same as the latest version.

Comment: For me it's work well with that : $.proxy(publicMethods.update, this)(data);

Comment: The additional arguments were added in jQuery 1.6:  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Answer (score 6):

xdazz is right, the latest 1.7.2 version has a different syntax, that also allows multiple extra arguments to be concated into the `apply` and passed into the proxy function, f.ex:

```
​var fn = function() {
    console.log(this.foo, arguments);
};

var obj = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

$.proxy(fn, obj, 'one', 'two')();
```

Running this code will print `bar ["one", "two"]`

You would get the same result by doing:

```
$.proxy(fn, obj)('one', 'two');
```

I might also add that none of this is documented in the official API, so things might work differently "under the hood" in different versions. This code is tested in 1.7.2.

Comment: I added another way to add params (see the last example) that seems to work in 1.5.2 as well if that is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/dNYKh/

Comment: @ThemeZ if this answer solved your problem, you should probably accept it as the best answer.

Comment: So others aren't confused, the above code does not print `bar ["one", "two"]` - the additional arguments are not passed as an array but as an Object:  `"bar" Arguments { 0: "one", 1: "two"}`.